# Python @classmethod & type hint for static builder returns: NameError: name '...' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I want to add type hint for static builder and Python 3 complaints that class name is not defined:

```
class Options(object):
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self._path = path

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

class Config(object):
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self._path = path

    @classmethod
    def from_options(cls, options: Options) -> Config:
        return cls(options.path)
```

on `python3 1.py` returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Config(object):
  File "1.py", line 14, in Config
    def from_options(cls, options: Options) -> Config:
NameError: name 'Config' is not defined
```

Comment: As an aside, you aren't correectly using a classmethod. If you are going to use a class method, then you *should* use the `cls` argument, in this case, `cls(options.path)`. Or else make it an actual `staticmethod`. Or in Python... just a module-level function (which can pretty much always serve the same purpose as a staticmethod).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Updated question. That typo slipped during extraction of problem from the code (typed from memory).

Answer (score 1):

The name of a class does not exist until after the `class ...` block ends.  If you wish to use the name as a type annotation on a method, you need to wrap it in quotes:

```
    @classmethod
    def from_options(cls, options: Options) -> "Config":
        return cls(options.path)
```

Comment: No, use `from __future__ import annotations`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a class name during the definition of that class. Generally, we shouldn't need to do so, but for type checking it makes perfect sense to need to reference a class during its own definition. Fortunately, the Python type hinting rules have a provision for this: [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references). Type names can appear as strings, provided the thing inside the string is a valid type.

```
@classmethod
def from_options(cls, options: Options) -> 'Config':
    return cls(options.path)
```

Comment: This is quite outdated. On Python 3.7+ you should use `from __future__ import annotations`. This becomes the default behavior in Python 3.10